# How to add multiple item using one key in python?

Tags: python, arrays, django

How to add multiple keys using one key in array?

```
def apidurusanalizi_func(self):
    isyerleri = data.iloc[:,0].values
    hatalar = np.delete(data.columns, 0)
    cluster1 = []
             for i,row in  enumerate(bc):
                   for j, y in enumerate(row):
                          if y:
                              isyeri = isyerleri[i]
                              hata = hatalar[j]
                              record = {"isyeri":str(isyeri), hata.lower().replace(" ", ""):hata}
                              if index == 0:
                                 cluster1.append(record)/*add record*/
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'cluster1': cluster1}, indent=2), content_type="application/json")
```

Output as below:

```
    {
      "cluster1": [
        {
          "isyeri": "15400002",/*the same key*/
          "olcmeodasi": "OLCME ODASI"
        },
        {
          "isyeri": "15400002",/*the same key*/
          "tipdegayari": "TIP DEG AYARI"
        }
    }
```

The format I want to take as JSON as below:

```
{
  "cluster1": [
    {
      "isyeri": "15400002", /* the same value for two values */
      "olcmeodasi": "OLCME ODASI"
      "tipdegayari": "TIP DEG AYARI"
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to convert your current output to an expected output @C.Uyar Please check below, Besides if you can provide a simplified code of what you are trying to do , with values of `data`, `bc` and `row` perhaps I can help further :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating your cluster not as dict, but as list: `cluster1 = []` and append dicts to it later: `cluster1.append(record)`. You should define `cluster1` as dict and set record values.

Your code is not stand-alone and can't be fully tested, but this should work:

```
def apidurusanalizi_func(data):
    isyerleri = data.iloc[:,0].values
    hatalar = np.delete(data.columns, 0)
    cluster1 = {}
    for i,row in  enumerate(bc):
        for j, y in enumerate(row):
            if y:
                isyeri = isyerleri[i]
                hata = hatalar[j]
                if index == 0:
                    cluster1["isyeri"] = str(isyeri)
                    cluster1[hata.lower().replace(" ", "")] = hata
    return HttpResponse(
        json.dumps({'cluster1': cluster1}, indent=2),
        content_type="application/json"
    )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.I got the output I wanted with some arrangements